# Image doesn't appear until you move to another tab and move back

Tags: html, css, image

A friend and I have been working on a website to get a bit of practice. It worked nominally on both our computers until we sent it to another friend. When they opened it in Chrome an image wouldn't appear until they moved to another tab, then re-visited the tab they had opened. It works fine on Chrome on both our machines and always has done. We've tried it on several other machines. They all suffer the same problem.

Any idea how we can remedy this? The page is [here](http://danielskelton.com/beeroclock/) for reference.

EDIT:

The precise image we're having problems with is the beer1.png not appearing on page load.

```
<div class="movingSquare">
 <img src="img/beer1.png" />
  <div id="bubbles">
...
  </div> <!-- #bubbles -->
</div> <!--.movingSquare -->
```

EDIT 2:

A lot of people are telling me it's fine but it's still rendering poorly on a few computers here. Here's a comparison on what you shouldn't be seeing first, then what you should be seeing.

Shouldn't see:
[image: Shouldn't be seeing]

Should see:
[image: Should be seeing]

Comment: Works fine on my computer Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m on Windows XP

Comment: Post the code you're having issues with. You can't expect people to debug your entire website for you.

Comment: @Coop added the part containing the troublesome image. Sorry.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code and it works fine in Chrome, I just tested it.

Comment: Image was loaded properly in Firefox 24,Win7

Comment: @Coop You're having beer appear and animated up the beer bottle rather than plain grey?

Comment: @Coop I've added demonstration images. I should have done that before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by adding a `left: 1px` style to the .movingSquare div. This causes the beer to appear as planned. Not sure how this fixed it, but it did.